# How can I vertically align my enumerate environment with answers package?

Tags: enumerate, answers

I'm using the [answers](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/answers) package to print my solutions at the end of my document. I would like to vertically align my a), b), c), etc. after the number of the exercise. For example, in the code below, you can see that for the answers of numbers 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4, the letter a) is indented more than the other letters. Is there a way to vertically align these letters ? Thanks in advance.

P.S. : Apologies for the bad grammar and syntax, english is not my first language and this is my first time at stackexchange. I apologise again for the breachs of protocol I undoubtebly did.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{rep}{Reponse}{rep}
\renewcommand{\Reponselabel}[1]{\textbf{#1.}}
\newtheorem{ex}{}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\Opensolutionfile{rep}[reponses_chapitre2_combinatoire]

\begin{ex}
Combien de nombres pairs de 3 chiffres peut-on former en utilisant sans     aucune répétition les chiffres : 1, 5, 6, 8 et 9?
\begin{rep}
$24$
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
De combien de façons peut-on ranger 6 livres sur une étagère si deux livres spécifiques...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item doivent être ensemble ?
\item ne doivent pas se suivre ?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item $240$
\item $480$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
De combien de façons un professeur peut-il placer les copies d'examen de ses 25 étudiants si la meilleure copie et la pire...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item doivent être ensemble ?
\item ne doivent pas se suivre ?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item $24!2!$
\item $25!-24!2!$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Un numéro de téléphone est constitué de 3 lettres suivies de 4 chiffres.    Combien de numéros peut-on faire si...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item on peut répéter les lettres et les chiffres?
\item on ne peut répéter que les lettres?
\item la première lettre ne peut être réutilisée?
\item on ne peut utiliser deux fois de suite la même lettre?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*] 
\item $26^3\cdot 10^4$
\item $26^3\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$
\item $26\cdot 25^2\cdot 10^4$
\item $26\cdot 25^2\cdot 10^4$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{rep} 

\clearpage

\section{Réponses}

\input{reponses_chapitre2_combinatoire}

\end{document}
```

[image: Test to vertically align enumerate]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No breaches of protocol or of English:) In fact, a perfectly phrased question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what layout you want exactly. But you could redefine the solution environment to force a line break. Probably one will have to add some penalties to avoid a page break.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{answers}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newsolution}[1]{%
   \@ifundefined{#1}{%
      \global\@definecounter{#1}%
      \global\@namedef{#1params}{{\Currentlabel}}%
      \newenvironment{#1}[1]%
      {%
         \refstepcounter{#1}%
         \csname pre#1\endcsname
         \trivlist
         \item[\hskip\itemsep{\@nameuse{#1label}{##1}}]\mbox{}}%
      {\csname post#1\endcsname\endtrivlist}%
      \global\@namedef{#1label}##1{\solutionstyle{##1}}%
   }{\typeout{WARNING: environment #1 already in use}}%
}
\Newassociation{rep}{Reponse}{rep}
\renewcommand{\Reponselabel}[1]{\textbf{#1.}}
\newtheorem{ex}{}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\Opensolutionfile{rep}[reponses_chapitre2_combinatoire]

\begin{ex}
Combien de nombres pairs de 3 chiffres peut-on former en utilisant sans     aucune répétition les chiffres : 1, 5, 6, 8 et 9?
\begin{rep}
$24$
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
De combien de façons peut-on ranger 6 livres sur une étagère si deux livres spécifiques...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item doivent être ensemble ?
\item ne doivent pas se suivre ?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item $240$
\item $480$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
De combien de façons un professeur peut-il placer les copies d'examen de ses 25 étudiants si la meilleure copie et la pire...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item doivent être ensemble ?
\item ne doivent pas se suivre ?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item $24!2!$
\item $25!-24!2!$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}
Un numéro de téléphone est constitué de 3 lettres suivies de 4 chiffres.    Combien de numéros peut-on faire si...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item on peut répéter les lettres et les chiffres?
\item on ne peut répéter que les lettres?
\item la première lettre ne peut être réutilisée?
\item on ne peut utiliser deux fois de suite la même lettre?
\end{enumerate}
\begin{rep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont{\alph*)},leftmargin=*]
\item $26^3\cdot 10^4$
\item $26^3\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$
\item $26\cdot 25^2\cdot 10^4$
\item $26\cdot 25^2\cdot 10^4$
\end{enumerate}
\end{rep}
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{rep}

\clearpage

\section{Réponses}

\input{reponses_chapitre2_combinatoire}

\end{document}
```

[image]